# Find the greatest value of $x$ satisfying $21\equiv 385\pmod x$ and $587\equiv 167\pmod x $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Problem**: Find the greatest value of $x$ satisfying $21\equiv 385\pmod x$ and $587\equiv 167\pmod x $.
>
> **Solution**: I think $21\equiv 385\pmod x$ is not possible.

There is some printing mistake in the question

Am I right?

Comment: That's fine, it just means that $x$ divides the difference $21 - 385$.

Comment: Then please help me in finding the ans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have $x$ divides $385 - 21 = 364$ and $x$ divides $587 - 167 = 420$.

All you have to do is to find the largest number that divides both $364$ and $420$. Maybe think about the *greatest common divisor*?

Comment: Then I think $28$ is the ans. Am I right ?

Comment: @rst: That sounds right :)

Comment: $587\equiv 167\pmod x $ means remainder is $587$ when $167$ divisible by $x$. How is it possible ?

Comment: @rst: $a \equiv b\;($mod $n)$ means that $n$ divides $a - b$ (or $b-a$).

Comment: But I think ,there is one more definition in terms of remainder. Here is the link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @rst $a\bmod n$ is the unique number $0\le r<n$ such that $a\equiv r\pmod n$. But that does not mean that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ implies $a\bmod n=b$. (It does imply $a\bmod n=b\bmod n$, however)

Comment: @rst: When you divide $a$ by $x$ you get a remainder $r$. That is you can write $a = nx + r$ for some unique remainder $0\leq r < x$.  Then $a - r = nx$ and this says exactly that $x$ divides $a-r$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and Thomas,Now my doubts are clear.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Your looking for the greatest integer $x$ such that $$21\equiv 385\pmod x\quad \text{and}\quad 587\equiv 167\pmod x $$

By definition $a\equiv b \pmod x$ means that $x$ divides $a - b$, which we denote as $x\mid (a - b)$.

So we have that $$x\mid (385 - 21) = 364\quad\text{and}\quad x\mid (587 - 167) = 420$$

The greatest integer $x$ dividing $a, b$ is the *greatest common divisor* of $a, b$: $\gcd(a, b)$. So in this case, we're looking for $x = \gcd(364, 420)$, where $\,364 = \color{blue}{\bf 4\cdot 7} \cdot 13$ and $420 = 3\cdot \color{blue}{\bf 4}\cdot 5 \cdot \color{blue}{\bf 7}$.

Hence, $x = \gcd(364, 420) = \color{blue}{\bf 4\cdot 7} = 28$.

Comment: G.M. my dear friend+

Comment: You always do great and I told you that. Look at mine. It is so below, Amy. It seems to me that the questions have been brought up in very special fields these days.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice color coding! +1

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned
$$
21\equiv385\pmod{x}\iff x\mid364
$$
and
$$
587\equiv167\pmod{x}\iff x\mid420
$$
Since, $420-364=56$, we know that $x\mid56$.

Since $364-6\cdot56=28$, we know that $x\mid28$.

Now, if we check, $28\mid364$ and $28\mid420$.

Therefore, since $x\mid28$ and both $28\mid364$ and $28\mid420$, we see that $x=28$ is the largest number that satisfies the given equivalences.